# how to get the row value of each column from linq

Tags: .net, linq

im new to linq. and I'm having problem extracting the value of each column from a single row..here's my code.

```
var websitedetail = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where x["CYBER_TY"].ToString() == "WEBSITE"
                    select x).FirstOrDefault();

        var test2 = websitedetail.Field<int>("CYBER_SERNO");
```

dt is a datatable with a source from database sp.this gives me a specified cast is not valid. I tried convert.toint32

thank you

Comment: This has nothing in common with LINQ. Your `websitedetail` variable is of type `DataRow`, and accessing the row fields is the same with or w/o LINQ. You can start by looking at the type of the value returned by `websitedetail["CYBER_SERNO"]`. Also `dt.Columns` and `websitedetail.ItemArray` properties.

Comment: thank you Ivan..the reason im using linq is..i have no control over the SP from our vendor..and I need to filter the  returned data. and reuse the values from these columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var websitedetail = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where x["CYBER_TY"].ToString() == "WEBSITE"
                    select x).FirstOrDefault();


var test2 = websitedetail.CYBER_SERNO
```

Linq objects are strongly typed; Meaning that your properties on your objects are columns in your row. For example

```
Database Table FOO:
ID
Name
Description
```

turnes into

```
FOO.FirstOrDefault().ID
```

or

```
FOO.FirstOrDefault().Description
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var websitedetail = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where x["CYBER_TY"].ToString() == "WEBSITE"
                    select x).select(y=>y.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please provide a little more information surrounding the fix to explain how it works...